# Is it possible in Wagtail to use a proxy model with RoutablePageMixin?

Tags: django, wagtail

My Wagtail site has certain items viewable in a gallery app, that the user can edit so that it would be also shown as an item in the shop app. It's strictly one-to-one, so I don't want them to be managing the items separately. I thought proxy models might be the best way to achieve this but I'm getting stuck and not finding very much documentation about using proxy models with Wagtail. Also possibly my regex is bad.

In app 'gallery':

```
class GalleryItem(Page):
    parent_page_types = ['InstallationPage']

    description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)
    direct_sale = models.BooleanField("Direct Sale", default=False, help_text="Check this box to list this item for sale directly on your website.")
    direct_sale_price = models.DecimalField("Sale price, $", blank=True, null=True, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, help_text="Add more info about this item for the store page only.")
    direct_sale_extra_description = models.CharField("Addtional sale description (optional)", blank=True, max_length=250, )
    stock = models.IntegerField("Number in stock", blank=True, null=True,)
```

In app 'shop':

```
from gallery.models import GalleryImage

class Shop(Page):

    def get_context(self, request):
        
        context = super().get_context(request)
        shop_items = ShopItem.objects.filter(Q(direct_sale=True) | Q(external_sale=True))
        paginator = Paginator(shop_items, 24)
        page = request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            pagin = paginator.get_page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            pagin = paginator.get_page(1)
        context['shop_items'] = shop_items

        return context

class ShopItem(GalleryItem, RoutablePageMixin):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    parent_page_types = ['Shop']

    @route(r"^shop/(?P<item_slug>[-\w]*)/$", name="item_view")
    def item_view(self, request, item_slug):
    # ????? Trying different things here:
        context = self.get_context(request)
        try:
            item = ShopItem.objects.get(slug=item_slug)
        except Exception:
             item = None

        if item is None:
            # 404
            pass
        context["item"] = item
    
        return render(request, "shop/shop_item.html", context)
```

The gallery item can be viewed at `/gallery/item-slug`. I would like to also view that item with a different template at `/shop/item-slug`, however I'm only able to achieve a 404 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RoutablePageMixin` doesn't work in the way you're imagining. For it to work, the page has to exist in the page tree and be findable through a normal path-based URL; any routes defined within it are then handled relative to that path. So, if you have a RoutablePageMixin page at `/foo/bar/baz/` that defines a view method with for `@route(r'^shop/([-\w]*)/$')`, that method will respond to URLs like `/foo/bar/baz/shop/item-slug/`. Since your tree doesn't have any pages that actually identify themselves as `ShopItem`, the route defined there will never be reached.

You don't really need a `ShopItem` model at all - all you're doing is responding to subpaths of `/shop/`, which is presumably the URL of your `Shop` page, so you can make `Shop` the RoutablePageMixin page instead:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class Shop(RoutablePageMixin, Page):

    def get_context(self, request):
        # ... logic for the main /shop/ page, as before

    @route(r'^([-\w]+)/$')  # view method for subpaths of /shop/
    def item_view(self, request, item_slug):
        item = get_object_or_404(GalleryItem, slug=item_slug)
        return render(request, "shop/shop_item.html", {'item': item})
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It does exactly what I was looking for. However I kept the proxy model for a nice route in the item's model admin /admin/shop/shopitem/. This would probably been easier for me if I had spent more time with plain Django.